Playwright - Issue with asserting (expect) iframe inside the shadow-root closed and across different origins
My html code looks like:
 #shadow-root (closed) == $0
<iframe src="https://challenges.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/turnstile/if/ov2/av0/rcv0/0/q9nst/0x4AAAAAAAVlQeNrI_m-kb9K/auto/fbE/normal/auto/" allow="cross-origin-isolated; fullscreen; autoplay" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups" id="cf-chl-widget-q9nst" tabindex="0" title="Widget containing a Cloudflare security challenge" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 65px;"></iframe>


I am trying to assert (expect) that this Cloudflare window is visible using Playwright and js.
But, I am not even able to access the element using Chrome console with:
document.querySelector("iframe[title='Widget containing a Cloudflare security challenge']");


Why my iframe code is not visible neither in the automation script nor in the Chrome console?
note:

When starting the script I am using:
launchOptions: {
args: ['--disable-web-security'],
}

this is how my expected element looks like

This is an internal network, so I can't share the URL unfortunately.

Example of my test


test('cloudflare', async ({ page }) => {
await page.goto("https://bscscan.com/contractsVerified");
await page.pause();

const frame = page.frameLocator("//iframe[@title='Widget containing a Cloudflare security challenge']");

await expect(frame.locator('//span[contains(text(), "Verify you are human")]')).toBeHidden();

const count = await frame.locator('//span[contains(text(), "Verify you are human")]').count();

console.log(`Element count: ${count}`);

});
Where the URL is a similar example of my URL

Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.

I edited the post. thanks for your vaiting. please review and provide your feedback. cheers

It would help to see the playwright code you are writing, but I suspect you will need to refer to this page in the documentation https://playwright.dev/docs/frames
You can also detect when a frame is added to the page using
page.on('frameattached')

and example can be found here https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-frame, for your usecase you could probably do something like this;
// when a frame is attatched to the page add it to an array
let frames = [];
page.on("frameattached", frame => {
  frames.push(frame);
    
});
//get the actual frame element 
const frameElement = frames[0].frameElement();

The last part gets the actual frameElement rather than the content i believe. You can find that documentation here https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-frame#frame-frame-element
Then you can probably assert that the frameElement is visible or something, I have not tested any of this but hopefully points you in the right direction

hey @Sirk, I provide edit to my post. thanks
